# HTTP_HOST Stripping via Firewalls and VPNs

Tags: django, cors, web-application-firewall, http-host

I have an issue that's presenting as a CORS-related issue from a frontend (React) making API calls to a backend (Django). However, looking at the logs, I'm seeing things like this:

> django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '123.456.789.101:8007'. You may need to add '123.456.789.101' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

The site works fine from my PC, several friends, and mobile devices, via *my* VPN, but fails to make API requests when behind certain firewalls (corporate) or via online VPN services that let one type in a website, visit it via an in-browser window (not naming names b/c that's beside the point here).

What *seems* to be the issue is a security measure whereby the firewalls are stripping out the HTTP_HOST specified by the site and adding in the actual IP to avoid e.g. HTTP_HOST-based spoofing.

Is there any way(s) to address this that doesn't involve assigning a static IP to my host and hard-coding that into the ALLOWED_HOSTS? For example, I like testing new apps on easy 1-click deploy type services like Digital Ocean, Railway, Netlify, etc. that are great but don't always provide the option for a static IP (not focusing on a specific service here).

Am I stuck hoping my PaaS provider exposes instance IPs as environment variables?

Currently considering an API gateway mapped to a static IP as it seems the most flexible, but it's often a bit overkill for small scale or small scope projects I work on.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to CORS.